# Spring Boot - Change the location of the /health endpoint to /ping/me

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator, health-monitoring

I set the `endpoints.health.path` property to `/ping/me`. But I cannot access the endpoint using http://localhost:9000/ping/me
It only works with http://localhost:9000/health. What am I missing ?
Here is the code in app properties file.

```
#Configuration for Health endpoint
endpoints.health.id=health
endpoints.health.path=/ping/me
endpoints.health.enabled=true
endpoints.health.sensitive=false

#Manage endpoints
management.port=9000
management.health.diskspace.enabled=false
```

The response I get is :

```
{
"timestamp" : 1455736069839,
"status" : 404,
"error" : "Not Found",
"message" : "Not Found",
"path" : "/ping/me"
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**See below for Spring Boot 2.***
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50364513/2193477

---

`MvcEndpoints` is responsible for reading `endpoints.{name}.path` configurations and somehow in its `afterPropertiesSet` method:

```
for (Endpoint<?> endpoint : delegates) {
            if (isGenericEndpoint(endpoint.getClass()) && endpoint.isEnabled()) {
                EndpointMvcAdapter adapter = new EndpointMvcAdapter(endpoint);
                String path = this.applicationContext.getEnvironment()
                        .getProperty("endpoints." + endpoint.getId() + ".path");
                if (path != null) {
                    adapter.setPath(path);
                }
                this.endpoints.add(adapter);
            }
}
```

It refusing from setting the `endpoints.health.path`, since `isGenericEndpoint(...)` is returning `false` for `HealthEndpoint`. Maybe it's a bug or something.

**Update:** Apparently this was a bug and got fixed in [`1.3.3.RELEASE`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/) version. So, you can use the `/ping/me` as your health monitoring path in this version.

Comment: It did not help. The application throws binding errors

Comment: Did you use the `/ping/me`? It's still an `id`, you can not use the `/` in `id`

Comment: Setting the id to 'ping' and path to 'ping' worked. But I can't specify hyphens like 'ping-me'. I was trying this based on documentation from the spring boot docs : "For example, to change the location of the /health endpoint to /ping/me you can set endpoints.health.path=/ping/me"

Comment: @Nagendra Kakarla you can use this feature in `1.3.3.RELEASE` version.

Answer (score 41):

The Actuator became technology-agnostic in Spring Boot 2.0.0, so it's not tied to MVC now. Thus if you use Spring Boot 2.0.x, you can just add the following config properties:

```
# custom actuator base path: use root mapping `/` instead of default `/actuator/`
management.endpoints.web.base-path=

# override endpoint name for health check: `/health` => `/ping/me`
management.endpoints.web.path-mapping.health=/ping/me
```

If you don't override the `management.endpoints.web.base-path`, your health-check will be available at `/actuator/ping/me`.

The properties like `endpoints.*` became deprecated in Spring Boot 2.0.0.

Comment: Helped me to change the actual actuator health check url. Thanks.