# How to change the default health endpoint used by spring boot admin

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-admin, health-check

I'd like to have a new on-demand health check endpoint for my service through implementation of indicator. The problem was the on-demand one would be called by default `/actuator/health`, so I have split the default health endpoint into two health groups `/actuator/health/default & /actuator/health/on-demand` as I didn't find any way to remove the on-demand directly from `/actuator/health`.

Now a new issue emerged, by default, spring boot admin will hit /actuator/health to get corresponding info, I was wondering it's possible to ask him to hit /actuator/health/default instead?

BTW, I only have admin client, without any recovery service

Comment: May be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35465556/spring-boot-change-the-location-of-the-health-endpoint-to-ping-me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

haha, this config is the answer: spring.boot.admin.client.instance.health-url